# Buying upgrades using different accumulated numbers of points

Tags: java

I am creating an incremental game like a cookie clicker... When the player has gained 20 points, they can buy a Super Click upgrade, which will then give them two points every time the button is clicked.  The next Super Click upgrade will cost 22 points, and give them 3 points per click. But in this case I manage to buy with 20 points, now it only buy the super click with 20 points continually but I want to switch to 22 points, What should do?... Thanks

Comment: Come back when you have written some code?

Comment: Please post what code you have written as an attempt. We don't write your programs for you.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Store a count of everytime the "buy" button is pressed and create a multiplier of 10% for every time it is pressed. As others have said here please post the code you have created so we can help you better.